# how does Elm handle responsive web design?

Tags: responsive-design, elm

I found this library for responsive CSS on github and then I started to ask myself... **is Elm responsive**?  Theoretically, Elm does anything that HTML, CSS and JavaScript can do... I do not see any ways to read inputs such as operating system or screen size.  And there may be other factors I am neglecting.

Perhaps one can write a port?

I have seen at least one case, F# where outside effects or requirements are handled by **comonads** but that is rather sophisticated solution.   Here is a blog on [co-effects](http://tomasp.net/blog/2014/why-coeffects-matter/) which talks about Context-aware programming.  It sounds sophisticated, but it's exactly what we want in responsive web pages.

[image]

*Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of responsive design is going to come from CSS via `@media` queries, so the main job of Elm is just to output HTML that isn't hard to style (e.g. avoiding tables for layout or inappropriate inline styles).

If you're wanting to dynamically do something based on the screen size, you can use the [`Window` package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/window/latest/Window), which can either issue a `Task` to retrieve the current size or subscribe to `resizes` events.

In general, I would expect that the output of an Elm program won't conflict with implementing a responsive design.

Comment: OK.  no special ways to handle media queries, but I had a port or something to ask my questions.  good enough, Elm is great

Comment: @johnmangual, I updated my answer to show that you don't need to use a port to get the screen size info, hope it helps!

Comment: oh!  [Window](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/window/1.0.1/Window) already exists!

Answer (score 1):

Here you find a step by step instruction how to create a responsive page with Elm: [Responsive Design with Elm Style Elements](https://becoming-functional.com/responsive-design-with-elm-style-elements-9d0eca8eb9ed). It avoids juggling with CSS but adjusts the HTML output.